# Trouble with web scraping in R?

Tags: html, r, web-scraping, rvest

In R, I am trying to webscrape the text of the following two webpages, using the CSS selector #article:

https://www.federalreserve.gov/monetarypolicy/fomcminutes20230201.htm
https://www.federalreserve.gov/monetarypolicy/fomcminutes20111102.htm

Here is an example of the code I run to web scrape the second link:

```
link2<-"https://www.federalreserve.gov/monetarypolicy/fomcminutes20111102.htm"

page=read_html(link2)
name=page%>%html_nodes("#article")%>%html_text() #earlier this was #press
name<-str_c(name, collapse=" ")
```

On the first webpage, this code works fine, and extracts all the desired text. However, when I run this code on the second link (the link displayed in the code block/example code), it only returns **empty spaces and zero actual text**. Can anyone help me understand why this code works fine on the first link but not the second?

Comment: I think I may have pasted in the wrong links in the initial post. perhaps try again?

Comment: Now it links to a page with compleatly different layout and structure, there is no `<div id="article">`.

Comment: Try `read_html(link2) %>% html_nodes("#printThis") %>% html_text()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As noted in comments, those 2 pages do not share layout and structure, so it's kind of expected that the `"#article"` selector returns different results (i.e. empty set)

If you are sure there's no id clash, you can combine selectors for both pages and use `"#article, #printThis"` for both types of pages:

```r
library(rvest)
library(stringr)

links <- c(link1 = "https://www.federalreserve.gov/monetarypolicy/fomcminutes20230201.htm",
           link2 = "https://www.federalreserve.gov/monetarypolicy/fomcminutes20111102.htm")

lapply(links, \(lnk)
         read_html(lnk) |>
         html_elements("#article, #printThis") |> 
         html_text() |> 
         str_squish() |>
         str_trunc(80)
)
#> $link1
#> [1] "Minutes of the Federal Open Market Committee January 31–February 1, 2023 A jo..."
#> 
#> $link2
#> [1] "Print Minutes of the Federal Open Market Committee November 1-2, 2011 FOMC Mi..."
```

<sup>Created on 2023-07-13 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>